# select query doesn't give result in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

> Select query don't show records array.

Below is my `get_all_user` method code.

```
public  function get_all_user(){

 $query = $this->db->query("select * from user");
 echo"<pre/>";print_r($query);die;
}
```

when i print $query it shows result_array() empty. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: use this
echo"<pre/>";print_r($query->result());die;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Should be like this :**

```
public function get_all_user()
{
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from user");
  $results = $query->result();
  echo"<pre/>";print_r($results);die;
}
```

*Or You can simply do like this :*

```
public function get_all_user()
{
  $results = $this->db->get("user")->result();
  print_r($results);die;
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Thanks It is really helpful.

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding